Higson's homotopy invariance result
I am learning about operator algebras and $KK$-theory, a result I find very striking is the following :

Any split-exact $K$-stable functor $F : C^*\text{-alg} \to \text{Ab}$ is necessarily homotopy invariant

where $C^*\text{-alg}$ is the category of (non necessarily unital), $C^*$-algebras, with the usual notion of homotopy theory and $K$ is the $C^*$-algebra of compact operators.
This was proven by Higson in 1988 (see "Algebraic $K$-theory of operator algebras", 1988) and it seems to be the most crucial ingredient in the proof of the Karoubi conjecture relating algebraic and topological $K$-theory of $C^*$-algebras. It was slightly generalised, and its proof was largely simplified later (see the book Topological and bivariant $K$-theory, Cuntz, Meyer, Rosenberg) but the proof is still quite technical, at least for me.
So what I would like to ask you is if any of you have some intuition behind this result ? Have you ever encountered an analogous result before in any other context (topology, homology/homotopy theory, study of groupoids)? I have read that $KK$-theory is analogous in some way to the theory of motives in algebraic geometry, is there such type of results in the theory of motives?
I know my question is rather vague but I am sure I am not the only one puzzled by this theorem...

It might be useful to read Section 3 of Cuntz's "A new look at KK-theory".
